# How to claim tokens from crowdloan after winning a Parachain slot

Tags: polkadot, kusama

We created a crowdloan campaign. We recently won the parachain slot. Now we want to know how users can claim their tokens which they contributed in crowdloan?

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations on winning the parachain slot! As the crowdloan campaign was successful, the tokens are now bonded till the end of the parachain lease. After the slot lease expires, anyone can trigger the refund for the contributed tokens through the permissionless `crowdloan.refund` extrinsic available on Polkadot JS Apps > Developer > Extrinsics page, by specifying the parachain ID.

Detailed information available here:
https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-crowdloans#supporting-a-crowdloan-campaign